# P(D^c|A^c) when given P(D|A^c)

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

So to my understanding, my teacher just told me that the following is incorrect:

If P(D|A^c)=0.4, then P(D^c|A^c) = 1-0.4 which is 0.6?

I was very sure this is true but she just said it's not as I need to work out the intersection and use a formula. Is what I put not correct??

Comment: What you wrote is correct, though perhaps your instructor wanted you to explain the result. You might, for example, write $P(D\cap A^c)+P(D^c\cap A^c)=P(A^c)$ and then conclude by using the definition of conditional probability.

Comment: Thanks to all for the feedback.  I did confuse $p(D|A^c)$ with $p(D\cap A^c)$, which is a clear mistake.  I have therefore deleted my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's written in the post is correct, though of course the instructor might have expected some argument for it.

One such argument would be to remark that $$(D\cap A^c)\cup (D^c\cap A^c)=A^c\implies P(D\cap A^c)+P(D^c\cap A^c)=P(A^c)$$

where we have used the fact that $D\cap A^c$ and $D^c\cap A^c$ are disjoint.

But then we have $$P(D\,|\,A^c)+P(D^c\,|\,A^c)=\frac {P(D\cap A^c)+P(D^c\cap A^c)}{P(A^c)}=1$$

which is the claim that you relied on.